# peer to peer chat with out the server

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, chat, p2p

I am trying to make a peer to peer chat program. the scenario is much more complicated but I will simplify it to get help in the the part where its needed.

as a summary:

**A- The Server**

1. There is a server waiting for clients to connect, when a client connects it will be kept as waiting till the next client connects.
2. When the 2nd client connects to the server the server will return to each client the ip and the port of the other client, so both client can talk to each other *without intervention of the server*.
3. Then the server back to 1

**B- The client**

1. the client start a tcpClient connection with server.
2. wait the server response.
3. client receive a custom object that contain the ip and the port of
   the other client
4. start chatting with the other client using the ip:port provided by
   the server of the other client.

The question is: is this possible considering network and firewall security configuration (default) on the client machine?

The client might be behind pating or nating router.

The application is going to run on the internet or local network.

Note: the thing i need help is it possible in C# to implemented the client part of the application to act as server and listen to a port and receive connections knowing that the port is not configured on the possible front end router;

Are there alternative solutions? The main idea is to keep the server out of the picture after server step 2

Comment: If your clients are under NATs (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) you won't be able to connect them directly, at least w/o hole punching. Hole punching works fine only for UDP (in most cases).